# Replacing words in c string

Tags: string

I'm having a slight problem with my code here.  I just made a small little program to test to put into my actual program.  The idea is to replace all the "(star)here(star)" with the string in the add variable.  However, when I run the program my final answer is not exactly correct.  These are my results:
I_have_a_star_which is super pretty

I_have_a_star_which is super pretty._That_is_great!_I_also_have_a_girlfriendwhich is super pretty

I_have_a_star_which is super pretty._That_is_great!_I_also_have_a_girlfriendwhich is super prett!

Any ideas on what the problem could be would be much appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main ( ) 
{
  char array[500] = "I_have_a_star_*here*._That_is_great!_I_also_have_a_girlfriend_*here*!",
  temp[500],
  add[500] = "which is super pretty";
  int i=0, j=0;

  while(array[i] != '\0')
  {
    if(array[i] != '*')
    {
      temp[j]=array[i];
      i++;
      j++;
    }
    else
    {
      strcat(temp,add);
      cout << temp << endl;
      i+=6;
      j+=strlen(add);
    }
  }

  cout << temp << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: just remove this line :--> "cout << temp << endl;"    becz no need to print in between.check following code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're copying characters into the `temp` array without initializing it or ever NUL terminating it.  So when you call `strcat` or try to print the contents of `temp` extra garbage on the end may screw things up.  Stick `memset(temp, 0, sizeof(temp));`
before your `while` loop or change the declaration to `temp[500] = ""`.  Alternately, you could add `temp[j] = '\0';` just before the call to `strcat` and just after then loop.

Answer (score 0):

Dude try this...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main ( ) 
{
  char array[500] = "I_have_a_star_*here*._That_is_great!_I_also_have_a_girlfriend_*here*!",
  temp[500],
  add[500] = "which is super pretty";
  int i=0, j=0;

while(array[i] != '\0')
{
  if(array[i] != '*')
  {
    temp[j]=array[i];
    i++;
    j++;
}
else
{
  strcat(temp,add);
  i+=6;
  j+=strlen(add);
 }
}

cout << temp << endl;

return 0;
}
```